# Is there a way to not copy custom field value when library item is copied?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, copy

I use SharePoint Online.

I have a custom field created in a library.
My item has some custom data in that field.
User decides to make copy of that item.

Is there a way to prevent that custom data being copied into the new copy ?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design that the column value will be copied if you have same column structure in the new destination library.

Currently, the way to avoid this is not to create the same custom column in the target library.